# What is the order of operations in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logic

This is a question from the app academy prep questions -- could someone explain the answer. I don't understand how the order of operations work in this while loop:

```
def dasherize_number(num)
  i = 0 
  dashed = ""
  num_s = num.to_s 

  while i < num_s.length
    digit = num_s[i].to_i
    if i > 0 
      prev_digit = num_s[i-1].to_i
      if prev_digit%2 == 1 || digit%2 == 1 
        dashed += "-" ## THIS LINE COMES FIRST

      end 
    end

    dashed += num_s[i] ## WHY IS THIS ADDED TO "DASHED" FIRST?

    i += 1
  end 
  return dashed
end

puts(dasherize_number(32467743))
```

the result is  3-245-7-7-4-3   so that all the odd numbers have a dash on either side except the end cases.

It doesn't make sense to me that the command to insert a dash is added to the new string after the original letter even though it comes first in the code.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean [operator precedence](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html)? You should probably step through this code and debug it better, outputting the results of each iteration.

Comment: Hint: `digit.odd?` might be more self-explanatory than the modulo trick.

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration of the while's block this condition is not true

```
if i > 0
```

But then the digit is added to `dashed` and from the next iteration even the condition is true and these two things together probably are confusing you

Comment: Ah okay, I gotcha. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

let's trace the first two iteration of `while` code.

`i = 0`
`num_s = "32467743"`

Inside the while loop.

- `digit = 3`, `i = 0`, `if i > 0 is false`, SO  `dashed = "3"`
- `digit = 2`, `i = 1`, `prev_digit = 3`, `if i > 0 is true`, `if prev_digit%2 == 1 || digit%2 == 1 is true`, SO  `dashed = "3-"`, then code exit `if i > 0` block, then dashed is being updated `dashed = 3-2`

everything works okay and in order.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few alternate solutions for educational purposes. This one uses `odd?` and `flat_map` to compile an array of character parts, then compacts them together and strips out unwanted chaff:

```
def dasherize_number(num)
  num.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).flat_map do |d|
    if (d.odd?)
      [ '-', d, '-' ]
    else
      d
    end
  end.join('').gsub(/\-\-+/, '-').sub(/\A\-/, '').sub(/\-\z/, '')
end
```

Here's one that works on a regular expression level by applying several substitutions in a row to get the final result:

```
def dasherize_number(num)
  {
    /([13579])/ => '-\1-',
    /\-\-+/ => '-',
    /\A\-/ =>  '',
    /\-\z/ => ''
  }.inject(num.to_s) do |n, (rx, sub)|
    n.gsub(rx,sub)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `puts` to trace what happens :

```
def dasherize_number(num)
  i = 0 
  dashed = ""
  num_s = num.to_s 
  puts "number=#{num_s}"

  while i < num_s.length
    digit = num_s[i].to_i
    if i > 0 
      prev_digit = num_s[i-1].to_i
      puts "prev_digit=#{prev_digit}   digit=#{digit}"

      if prev_digit%2 == 1 || digit%2 == 1 
        dashed += "-" ## THIS LINE COMES FIRST
        puts "dashed in if=#{dashed}"
      end 
    end

    dashed += num_s[i] ## WHY IS THIS ADDED TO "DASHED" FIRST?
    puts "dashed + num=#{dashed}"

    i += 1
  end 
  return dashed
end

puts(dasherize_number(32467743))
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 
number=32467743
dashed + num=3
prev_digit=3   digit=2
dashed in if=3-
dashed + num=3-2
prev_digit=2   digit=4
dashed + num=3-24
prev_digit=4   digit=6
dashed + num=3-246
prev_digit=6   digit=7
dashed in if=3-246-
dashed + num=3-246-7
prev_digit=7   digit=7
dashed in if=3-246-7-
dashed + num=3-246-7-7
prev_digit=7   digit=4
dashed in if=3-246-7-7-
dashed + num=3-246-7-7-4
prev_digit=4   digit=3
dashed in if=3-246-7-7-4-
dashed + num=3-246-7-7-4-3
3-246-7-7-4-3
```

> dashed += num_s[i] ## WHY IS THIS ADDED TO "DASHED" FIRST?

The loop starts with i = 0, so that the `if i > 0` is not executed.

> dashed += "-" ## THIS LINE COMES FIRST

Yes, first in the lines, but not in execution, precisely because it is in the then block depending of the `if i > 0`, which is not executed during the first iteration, allowing `dashed += num_s[i]` to add the first number to the empty `dashed` string.

```
dashed + num=3
```

It's only in the second iteration that i = 1, so that `if i > 0` becomes true and allows `dashed += "-"` to be executed :

```
dashed in if=3-
```